# How can I change the DeviceID on my Android Virtual Device?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have an existing AVD I'm running in the Android emulator, but I'd like to change its Device ID.  Can this be done either in Android SDK and AVD Manager or by editing any of the files in my ~/.android directory?

Comment: What exactly is "its Device ID"?

Comment: The hardware ID as reported by GetDeviceID(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I am not aware of a way to set or change the device ID in an emulator image. If there is one, it is undocumented.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can, if you are willing to edit the databases on your emulator using sqlite3